# Reading parts of a file after a specific tag is found in C using fgets

Tags: c, file, fgets

I would like some suggestion on how to read an 'XML' like file in such a way that the program would only read/store elements observed in a node that meets some requirements. I was thinking about using two fgets in the following way:

```
while (fgets(file_buffer,line_buffer,fp) != NULL)
 {
   if (p_str = (char*) strstr(file_buffer,"<element of interest opening")) )
    {
      //new fgets that starts at fp and runs only until the end of the node
       {
         //read and process
       }
    }
 }
```

Does this make sense or are there smarter ways of doing this?

Secondly (in my idea), will i have to define a new FILE* (like fr), set fr to fp at the start of the second fgets or can i somehow abuse the original filepointer for that?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use a memory mapped file?  Everything then becomes a pointer operation for you while the OS manages the memory in the background.

Comment: @JimR I could, I have never worked with it before so let me do some reading up on it.

Answer (score 2):

Use an XML parser like Xmllib2 http://xmlsoft.org/xml.html

Comment: It's not really XML sadly, I should have made that clearer in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems isn't bad for the job.

You could read the whole line from the file, then, process it using sprintf, strstr or whatever functions you like. This will save you time and unnecessary overheads with FILE I/O.

As per your second idea, you can use `fseek()`(Refer: `man fseek`) or `rewind()`(Refer: `man rewind`) using the same file pointer `fp`. You do not need an extra file pointer.

EDIT:

If you could change the tag format to adhere to XML structure you will be able to use libXML2 and such libraries properly.

If that's not possible, then you have to write your own parser.
A few pointers:

1. First extract data from the file into a buffer.The size of the buffer and whether dynamically or statically allocated, will depend on your specs.
2. Search in the buffer, if non-whitespace character is `<` or whatever character your tag usually begins with. If not, you can just show an error and exit.
3. Now follows the tag name, until the first whitespace, or the / or the > character. Store them. Process the =, strings and stuff, as you wish.
4. If the next non-whitespace character is /, check that it is followed by >(or a similar pattern in your specs to find if a tag ends). If so, you've finished parsing and can return your result. Otherwise, you've got a malformed tag and should exit with an error.

   If the character is >, then you've found the end of the begin tag. Now follows the content.
   Otherwise what follows is an argument. Parse that, store the result, continue at step 4.
5. Read the content until you find a < character.
6. If that character is followed by /, it's the end tag. Check that it is followed by the tag name and >. If yes, return the result , else, throw an error.
7. If you get here, you've found the beginning of a nested XML. Parse that with this algorithm and then continue at 4 again.

Although, its quite basic idea, I hope it should help you start.

EDIT:
If you still want to reference the file as a pointer consider using `mmap()`.

If you add `mmap` with a bit of `shared memory` IPC and adequate memory locking stuff, you could write a parallel processing program, that will process most of your files faster.

Comment: With this approach you also have to handle multiline cases

Comment: yes, you have to know handle multiline cases, but since most of the operations will occur in RAM, it would be faster. Since, OP didn't specify how large the XML files or how complex they would be it would be difficult.

Comment: I got called in to the lab, sorry for the late response. The files typically range from a few 100 meg to several gig

Comment: I have a basic parser already for the type of file but that just reads everything into memory and then processes it. I was hoping to write it in such a way that it reads the file, encounters a node that is matching some criteria and then read all parts belonging to that node. This is the reason why i was thinking about two file pointers and limited the second fgets to a certain amount of lines <OR> untill it reaches a node end indicator, then setting the original fp to where the new fp was at the end of the node. I hope this clarifies it a bit?

Comment: yes, but file i/o is very slow compared to memory i/o. So, that basic parser is better than FILE pointer approach on such large file size. You can always use `rewind()` function to reset your FILE* without closing and opening it again or needing a second FILE*.